# Typedef in TypeScript error: 'expected variableDeclarator'

Tags: typescript, tslint

Running tslint on my code I get this error:

```
expected variableDeclarator: 'getCode' to have a typedef.
```

for a TypeScript file:

```
export var getCode = function (param: string): string {
    // ...
};
```

How do I improve this so I don't see the tslint error?

Comment: Have you tried adding a type declaration to `getCode`? I mean `export var getCode : (param: string) => string = function (param: string): string { ... } `

Comment: Kuba, that's the correct solution - at least for making tslint happy. However I don't think the code is readable after this. If you add an answer I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: Guess I have to withdraw my comment on readability after I have become a little wiser :-)

Comment: Okay, added the answer. I wasn't sure if this was the reason, therefore I just posted it as a comment :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to explicitely add a type declaration to your variable.

```
export var getCode : (param: string) => string = function (param: string): string { 
    //...
}
```

You said this looks pretty unreadable. Well, yes, anonymous types makes TS code look worse, especially when they are huge. In that case, you can declare a callable interface, like this:

```
export interface CodeGetter {
    (param: string): string;
}

export var getCode: CodeGetter = function(param: string): string { ... }
```

You can check whether tslint allows you (I can't check it right now) to drop type declaration in definition of the function when using the interface

```
export interface CodeGetter {
    (param: string): string;
}

export var getCode: CodeGetter = function(param) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code fragment looks fine. If this function is made to return a string, it compiles in tsc without an error. Are you sure the return value is a string?

This excerpt is from the tslint repo:

> typedef enforces type definitions to exist. Rule options:
>
> ```
> "callSignature" checks return type of functions
> "indexSignature" checks index type specifier of indexers
> "parameter" checks type specifier of parameters
> "propertySignature" checks return types of interface properties
> "variableDeclarator" checks variable declarations
> "memberVariableDeclarator" checks member variable declarations
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Add a typedef to getCode:

```
var getCode: (s: string) => string;
```

Inline, it should look like this:

```
export var getCode: (s: string) => string = function (param) {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: I made tslint stop complaining with a few additions to your suggestion.
export var getCode: (s: string) => string = function (param: string): string {//...} This looks really ugly and unreadable, and if that's the answer I prefer removing that tslint check.